# CSS @media query not working correctly

Tags: css, media-queries

There is a need to scale media requests with one image (logo) for each mobile device: iPhone 5, 6, 6+, iPad's, as well as on large screens.
Accordingly, I almost need to specify a style in the form of width, etc. For portrait and landscape orientation.
Of all works only for the iPhone 6, iPad's and large screens (=> 1600px)
For small screens (320x480) and iPhone 6+ does not work (check in Chrome)

For iPhone 6+ media query applied as for iPhone 5...

Tell me please, what's wrong in my code?
I will be extremely grateful!

Here's the CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) and (max-width : 480px) {
.logo-mobile img {
    width: 150px;
    transform: translateY(-7px); 
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width : 480px) {
.logo-mobile img {
    width: 150px;
    transform: translateY(-7px); 
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-height: 568px) and 
(orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
.logo-mobile img {
    width: 144px;
    transform: translateY(-7px);
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-height: 568px) and 
(orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
.logo-mobile img {
    width: 144px;
    transform: translateY(-7px);
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 375px) and (max-height: 667px) and 
(orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
.logo-mobile img {
    width: 144px;
    transform: translateY(-8px);
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 375px) and (max-height: 667px) and 
(orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
.logo-mobile img {
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-11px);
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 414px) and (max-height: 736px) and 
(orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
.logo-mobile img {
    width: 144px;
    transform: translateY(-8px);
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 414px) and (max-height: 736px) and 
(orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
.logo-mobile img {
    width: 144px;
    transform: translateY(-8px);
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) and 
(orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 
.logo-mobile img {
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-8px);
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) and 
(orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
.logo-mobile img {
     width: 100%;
    transform: translateY(5px);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
.logo-mobile img {`enter code here`
    width: 100%;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you could start by ensuring you added the meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

You could also consider adding appropriate prefixes to your CSS3 selectors like so...

```
-webkit-transform: translateY(8px)//Chrome
-o-transform: translateY(8px) //Opera
```

and so on. You could check w3schools for a complete list of css3 prefixes. I hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The meta tag is present. I went too hard). I will study further